# Delete emails from outlook via powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm trying to run a powershell script on a shared mailbox (Exchange). when I run the script on my personal mailbox it works, altough when I change it to the share one I only get error messages.

```
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

$logfile = $PSScriptRoot + "\email.log"

$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

$folder = $namespace.Folders.Item('shared.mailbox@company.com').Folders.Item('Inbox')

$folder_2 = $namespace.Folders.Item('shared.mailbox@company.com').Folders.Item('Deleted Items')

$date_check = (get-date).AddDays(-1)  | Get-Date -UFormat "%m-%d-%Y"

$date_check_deleted_items = (get-date).AddDays(-2)  | Get-Date -UFormat "%m-%d-%Y"

$emailToDelete = $folder.items | Where-Object { $_.ReceivedTime -lt $date_check; }

$emptyDeletedItems = $folder_2.items | Where-Object { $_.ReceivedTime -lt $date_check_deleted_items; }

Get-Date | Out-File $logfile -Append
"Amount of emails being deleted:" | Out-File $logfile -Append
$emailToDelete.Count | Out-File $logfile -Append
"Subject of Emails in the Inbox folder:" | Out-File $logfile -Append
$emailToDelete.subject | Out-File $logfile -Append
"Amount of emails being deleted from deleted items:" | Out-File $logfile -Append
$emptyDeletedItems.Count | Out-File $logfile -Append
"Subject of Emails in the Deleted Items folder folder:" | Out-File $logfile -Append
$emptyDeletedItems.subject | Out-File $logfile -Append
write-host "Emails received before" $date_check "(MM/dd/YYYY) will be deleted"
write-host "deleting emails in 5"
Start-Sleep -s 1
write-host "deleting emails in 4"
Start-Sleep -s 1
write-host "deleting emails in 3"
Start-Sleep -s 1
write-host "deleting emails in 2"
Start-Sleep -s 1
write-host "deleting emails in 1"
Start-Sleep -s 1
write-host "deleting" $emailToDelete.Count "emails"


#$EmailToDelete.Delete()

write-host $emptyDeletedItems.count "Emails to be deleted from the deleted items folder"
write-host "Emails received before" $date_check_deleted_items "(MM/dd/YYYY) will be deleted from that folder"

$emptyDeletedItems.Delete()

write-host $emailToDelete.count "Emails are deleted from the Inbox folder and" $emptyDeletedItems.count "Emails are deleted from the Deleted Items folder, application will close in 5 seconds"
Start-Sleep -s 5
```

I'm receiving the following errors:

```
The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\emails.ps1:7 char:1
+ $folder = $namespace.Folders.Item('shared.mailbox@company.com').Fold ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found.
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\emails.ps1:9 char:1
+ $folder_2 = $namespace.Folders.Item('shared.mailbox@company.com').Fo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Could you help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest against using outlook COM objects for this. A much better approach is using either the EWS API or Microsoft Graph for these kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to run a powershell script on a shared mailbox (Exchange)

Not exactly so. You are trying to automate Outlook with a shared mailbox. And the account is configured locally in Outlook. It seems you can't access it form a shared location.

Another aspect is that Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.